# REST sub resource with DTOs and Generics, getting Type Erasure error

Tags: java, generics, jax-rs, java-ee-7, type-erasure

I'm working on a rather complex model to handle any DTO/Entity type.  Each DTO has it's own REST endpoint, but will be using a common generic sub resource to read/write from the database.  I'm getting a type erasure error, though, and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

First, here is an example Entity and corresponding DTO:

**Entity**:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "ID Required!")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Name Required!")
    private String name;

}
```

**DTO Utility interface**:

```
public interface DTO<Entity extends AbstractEntity, PrimaryKey> {
   /* utility methods here */
}
```

**DTO**:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyEntityDTO implements DTO<MyEntity, Integer> {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Ok, now moving onto the REST api.

**API**:

```
@Path("/stuff")
@RequestScoped
public class StuffFacade {

    @Inject
    EntityMappedManager entityMappedManager;

    @Path("/my-items")
    public StuffFacade.EntityFacade<MyEntity, Integer, MyEntityDTO> myEntityFacade() {
        return new StuffFacade.EntityFacade<>(getAccessor(), MyEntityDTO::new);
    }

    @Path("/your-items")
    public StuffFacade.EntityFacade<YourEntity, String, YourEntityDTO> yourEntityFacade() {
        return new StuffFacade.EntityFacade<>(getAccessor(), YourEntityDTO::new);
    }


    @Produces
    @Override
    public <E extends AbstractEntity, P> DatastoreAccessor<E, P> getAccessor() {
        return new DatastoreAccessor<E, P>() {

            @Override
            public List<E> findAll(QueryParams queryParams) {
                return entityMappedManager.findAll(getEntityClass());
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<E> findById(P id) {
                return Optional.ofNullable(entityMappedManager.findById(getEntityClass(), id));
            }

            @Override
            public E create(E entity) {
                return entityMappedManager.save(entity);
            }

            @Override
            public E update(E entity) {
                return entityMappedManager.save(entity);
            }

            @Override
            public E remove(E entity) {
                return entityMappedManager.remove(entity);
            }

        };
    }

        public class EntityFacade<Entity extends AbstractEntity, PrimaryKey, DTOType extends DTO<Entity, PrimaryKey>> extends DTOFacade<Entity, PrimaryKey, DTOType> {

            private final DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> datastoreAccessor;
            private final Function<Entity, DTOType> dtoMapper;

            public EntityFacade(DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> datastoreAccessor, Function<Entity, DTOType> dtoMapper) {
                this.datastoreAccessor = datastoreAccessor;
                this.dtoMapper = dtoMapper;
            }

            @Override
            public DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> getDatastoreAccessor() {
                return this.datastoreAccessor;
            }

            @Override
            public GenericEntity<ListMetadata<DTOType>> getGenericEntity(List<DTOType> list) {
                return new GenericEntity<List<DTOType>>(list) {
                };
            }

            @Override
            public Function<Entity, DTOType> getDTOMapper() {
                return this.dtoMapper;
            }

        }

}
```

**DTOFacade**:

```
 public static abstract class DTOFacade<Entity extends AbstractEntity, PrimaryKey, DTOType extends DTO<Entity, PrimaryKey>> {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response findAll(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        QueryParams queryParams = new QueryParams(uriInfo.getQueryParameters());
        List<Entity> results = getDatastoreAccessor().findAll(queryParams);
        List<DTOType> converted = new ListMetadata<>(
                results.getList().stream()
                .map(getDTOMapper())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), results.getParentSize());
        return Response.ok(getGenericEntity(converted)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response findById(@PathParam("id") PrimaryKey id) {
        Optional<Entity> optionalEntity = getDatastoreAccessor().findById(id);
        if (!optionalEntity.isPresent()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(optionalEntity.map(getDTOMapper()).get()).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response create(DTOType entity) {
        DTOType created = getDTOMapper().apply(getDatastoreAccessor().create(toObjectModel(entity)));
        return Response.ok(created).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response update(DTOType entity) {
        DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> datastoreAccessor = getDatastoreAccessor();
        Optional<Entity> e = datastoreAccessor.findById(entity.getId());
        if (!e.isPresent()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(getDTOMapper().apply(datastoreAccessor.update(toObjectModel(entity)))).build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response delete(@PathParam("id") PrimaryKey id) {
        DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> datastoreAccessor = getDatastoreAccessor();
        Optional<Entity> entity = datastoreAccessor.findById(id);
        if (!entity.isPresent()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(getDTOMapper().apply(datastoreAccessor.remove(entity.get()))).build();
    }

    public abstract DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> getDatastoreAccessor();

    public abstract GenericEntity<List<DTOType>> getGenericEntity(List<DTOType> list);

    public abstract Function<Entity, DTOType> getDTOMapper();

    public Entity toObjectModel(DTOType e) {
        return e.toObjectModel();
    }
}
```

**DatastoreAccessor**:

```
public interface DatastoreAccessor<Entity extends AbstractEntity, PrimaryKey> {

    List<Entity> findAll(QueryParams queryParams);

    Optional<Entity> findById(PrimaryKey id);

    Entity create(Entity entity);

    Entity update(Entity entity);

    Entity remove(Entity entity);

    default Class<Entity> getEntityClass() {
        return ((Class<Entity>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

**EntityMappedManager**:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EntityMappedManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;

    public <T extends AbstractEntity, P> T findById(Class<T> clazz, P id){
        return em.find(clazz, id);
    }


    public <T extends AbstractEntity> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(clazz);
        Root<T> root = query.from(clazz);
        query.select(root);
        return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
    // OTHER METHODS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
}
```

**ERROR**
Finally, when trying to `GET` `/stuff/my-items` I get a **Type Erasure** error:

```
Severe:   Following issues have been detected: 
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(java.lang.Object) at index 0.
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(java.lang.Object) at index 0.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type PrimaryKey from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(PrimaryKey) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type DTOType from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.update(DTOType) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type PrimaryKey from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(PrimaryKey) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type DTOType from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.create(DTOType) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.mypackage.rest.v1.ApplicationV1]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.mypackage.rest.v1.ApplicationV1 threw exception
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Model validation error(s) found in sub resource returned by sub resource locator.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(java.lang.Object) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@5ad223e4]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(java.lang.Object), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.Object, source=id, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type PrimaryKey from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(PrimaryKey) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.findById(java.lang.Object)', [WARNING] Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type DTOType from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.update(DTOType) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.update(com.mypackage.DTO)', [WARNING] Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(java.lang.Object) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=DELETE, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@51c006a5]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(java.lang.Object), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.Object, source=id, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type PrimaryKey from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(PrimaryKey) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.delete(java.lang.Object)', [WARNING] Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type DTOType from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.create(DTOType) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.mypackage.DTOFacade.create(com.mypackage.DTO)', [WARNING] Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 2 of type com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)', [WARNING] Parameter 3 of type java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType> from public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor<Entity, PrimaryKey>,java.util.function.Function<Entity, DTOType>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade$EntityFacade(com.mypackage.rest.v1.StuffFacade,com.mypackage.DatastoreAccessor,java.util.function.Function)']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter$1.run(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.validate(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.apply(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.mypackage.servlet.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Aside from the non fatal warnings, the actual exception is caused by something completely different. It's from `PrimaryKey` not being injectable as a `@PathParam`. Look at the javadoc for `@PathParam` for the rules pertaining to use of custom type injection.

Comment: If you look at `DTOFacade`, you'll see that `PrimaryKey` is really a type parameter, which is set at `EntityFacade` (an embedded class of the `API`), which is defined through type inference with the return type of `StuffFacade.EntityFacade<MyEntity, Integer, MyEntityDTO>` on `myEntityFacade()`.  I'm not seeing how `@PathParam` is relevant.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. One way to get it to work is to create a subclass of EntityFacade passing the type arguments., and returning that subtype.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: Well, I wasn't able to get that to work, so I ended up passing the class to the DTOFacade constructor.